# Routing, Views, AngularJs problems ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i ma having a little problem with my the routing technique in AngularJs, i followed a tutorial and i believe i did not make a mistake, so I am hoping you will prove me wrong and show me the mistake.

here is my routing file :

```
app.config(["$routeProvider",
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/story-1",{
            templateUrl: "views/view.html"
        })

        .when("/story-2",{
            templateUrl: "views/view.html"
        })

        .when("/story-3",{
            templateUrl: "views/view.html"
        })

        .when("/story-4",{
            templateUrl: "views/view.html"
        })

        .when("/story-5",{
            templateUrl: "views/view.html"
        })
}])
```

My app declaration (app.js):

```
var app = angular.module("App",["ngRoute"])
```

My html File :

```
<section id="application">
<div class="un-tiers">
    <div class="routes">
        <div class="route">
            <a href="#!/story-1">Jacline</a>
        </div>
        <div class="route">
            <a href="#!/story-2">The Worst Doctor</a>
        </div>
        <div class="route">
            <a href="#!/story-3">Mr Client</a>
        </div>
        <div class="route">
            <a href="#!/story-4">Monsieur Garnier</a>
        </div>
        <div class="route">
            <a href="#!/story-5">Il était une fois</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="deux-tiers" ng-view>
</div>
</section>
```

My app is declared in the body :

```
<body ng-app="App">
```

My imported files needed :

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="Routing.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: whats the issue you are getting?

Comment: @Sravan when i click my links i get nothing! no view

Comment: is there any error on console you see?

Comment: i added an alert in my file Routing and my alert doesnt shows up, so the problem is my programm is not executing the file routing, dont know why..

Comment: Nothing in my console concerning this :(

Comment: is `Routing.js` capital file name, also use `angular.module("App").config`

Comment: Sravan : no no, well it was only a stupid mistake i made, everything is fine now, thank you sir for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having route in different file, you need to inject that into your main module.

if your router file add

angular.module('myApp.routes', [])

```
.config(["$routeProvider",function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "your fallback route"
        })
```

}])

Inside your app.js file

var app = angular.module("App",["ngRoute", "myApp.routes"])

Comment: Hello, no I am not having route i different file, i added an alert in my file Routing and my alert doesnt shows up, so the problem is my programm is not executing the file routing, dont know why..

Comment: Sridhar : Hello again, I am so srry friend, a stupid mistake, i declared my app in other file and when i copied the declaration in my file app.js but copied and not cuted hahaha so it was my app declaration problem.. Thank you so much for your precious time

Comment: Anytime.@TaouBen